# Attempt to implement scheduler in STM32F4 Discovery

Tags: c, function-pointers, scheduler, multitasking, stm32f4discovery

I have a question regarding scheduler implementation. I have tried to implement a scheduler according to my understanding.

In this example, i have taken advantage of the Systick handler provided by STM32, so my handler looks somewhat like this:

```
void SysTick_Handler(void)
{
  HAL_IncTick();
  HAL_SYSTICK_IRQHandler();    

  if(ticks_for_scheduler++==100)
      ticks_for_scheduler=0;    
}
```

I have a scheduler.h file which looks like this:

```
void (*task1)() = read_temp;
void (*task2)() = Display_temp_lcd;
```

and my scheduler.c looks like this:

```
extern uint16_t ticks_for_scheduler;
void sched_system()
{

  if(ticks_for_scheduler==20)
      (*task1)();

  if(ticks_for_scheduler==40)
  {
      (*task2)();
  }   
}
```

The function `sched_system` is called in `main(){while(1){sched_system();}`My goal is to execute `task1` every 20ms, and `task2` every 40ms, but somehow I'm not able to get it right. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong? I don't see the results on my LCD as expected.

Comment: Do not reinvert the wheel. Just see how Freedie has implemented it http://distortos.org/

Comment: You can look as well in the source code of FreeRTOS http://www.freertos.org/

Comment: Moreover your "sched_system" ifs should look like this: if(ticks_for_scheduler%20==0) and you should reinitialize at multiple of 40 (i.e. f(ticks_for_scheduler++==120).

Comment: @FrankPak Thanks for the response, you're right thats the right way to go, but, I don't thing that would work either because I'm not sure which task would execute let's say at tick number 80. I would do something like if(ticks_for_scheduler++==50) and execute tasks at if(ticks_for_scheduler%5==0)(*task1()); and if(ticks_for_scheduler%11==0)(*task2());

Comment: yes you can do it, however things are bit more complicated. I suppose that your sched_system is executed in a cycle so you obviously don't know which task (or better function) is executing because you don't know how many ticks the function spends in execution. So to be sure that each function is executed at that time you need preemption and obviously context switch. However assuming that you measure the ticks that each function spends in execution you can go as you describe.